# Non-ASCII Unicode symbols with their word equivalents

Tags: data-request, nlp

I am looking for a dataset containing Unicode symbols with some word equivalent.

Examples:

- `©`: copyright
- `€`: euro
- `√`: square root

Answer (score 2):

[W3C Character Reference Chart](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) has this and also HTML/hexadecimal equivalents. Should be an easy scrape, or a not very tedious manual job.

Answer (score 1):

The official Unicode names list has names for all characters.

The [official names list](http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/NamesList.txt) does not contain the corresponding symbols, but those are easy to get in any markup or programming language.

Alternately, you can use sources such as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters), [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm) or [codepoints.net](https://codepoints.net/) for the same.